# how to breakdown seearch result with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in my elasticsearch that represent suppliers, each document is a supplier and each supplier have branches as well, it looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "supplierName": "John Flower Shop",
    "supplierAddress": "107 main st, Los Angeles",
    "branches": [
        {
            "branchId": 11,
            "branchName": "John Flower Shop New York",
            "branchAddress": "34 5th Ave, New York"
        },
        {
            "branchId": 12,
            "branchName": "John Flower Shop Miami",
            "branchAddress": "56 ragnar st, Miami"
        }
    ]
}
```

currently I exposed api to allow search in fields: supplierName, supplierAddress, branchName and branchAddress.

the use case is a search box in my website, that perform a call to the backend, and pur the result in a dropdown for the user to choose the supplier.

my issue is, given the example document above, if you search for "John Flower Shop Miami", the answer will be the whole document, and what will be presented is the top level supplier name.

what I want is to present "John Flower Shop Miami", and im not sure how to understand what part of the result is what hit the search....

does someone had to do something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Handling relationship in elasticsearch is a bit of work but you can do it. I recommend you to read the ES guide's chapter [handling relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) to have the big picture.

Then my advice is to index your branches as [nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). Thus they will be stored as distinct documents in your index.

It will require you to change your query syntax to use [nested queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-nested-query.html) that can be a pain in the a... but in exchange, you will be granted with [inner_hits functionality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html).

It will allow you to know which subdocument ( nested document ) matched your query.

Comment: thanks for the answer. my problem is that I use mongo, and what I use to sync my mongo and es is mongo-connector (https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector) which over there i just set up my "namespace" to be "myDb.myCollection" : true" and then this connector keeps my es update in every op in the db

Comment: then you have to implement the logic on the application side, but good luck since it can be hard to understand in the application which branch matches through analysis chain ( and that why we use elasticsearch :D )

Comment: yes i know :\ so what you mean is basically in the server side to filter the results? with my language, which is scala

Comment: yes, but I think its a bad pattern. You can't just duplicate your mongo documents into elasticsearch. You will be confronted soon or later to the limitations of not modeling your data for your search needs. My advice is so to start transforming your data between mongo and elastic to fit your users' search patterns.

Comment: I totally agree. I checked out the link for the nested documents in your answer. it definitely looks like what I need, the only thing is that im trying to understand how to change my current mappings to be nested...i dont mind also creating my index again but as I told you im using a connector that creates me the index with my collection name as a type. so now can I override the meppings that already created?

Comment: for now when i get my mappings i see that branches are of type boolean...i thought it would be array - "branches": {
            "properties": {
              "active": {
                "type": "boolean"

Comment: i think its because im inserting jsons...i have to work like that cause im syncing with mongodb

Comment: it is only the active property of your branches that is boolean. You branch attribute seems to be of type object. For all the stuff about mongo connector and managing the mapping i cant help you sorry